# How to change this regular html form into django form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to change the following HTML form:

```
@transaction.atomic
def Register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.POST['first_name']
        lname = request.POST['last_name']

        mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        """This section replaces multiple characters with blank value
        so that the mobile number has nothing except numeric values
        """
        rep = ['+', '-', ' ', '.']
        for i in rep:
            mobile = mobile.replace(i, '')

        company = request.POST['company']
        email = request.POST['email']

        u = User.objects.create_user(mobile, email, '1234', first_name=fname, last_name=lname)
        u.save()

        p = UserProfile.objects.create(user=u, company=company, mobile=mobile)
        p.save()

        return HttpResponse("Registration complete! Please head over to the <a href='/login/'>login page</a> to start using your SMS panel.")

    return render(request, "message/register.html", {})
```

Into a Django form mainly because I need to learn how to use them, also I need all the fields to be filled up before the registration completes, I don't want any optional fields. The following is what I've come up with from the documentation.

**views.py**

```
@transaction.atomic
def Register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # I guess this is where I need help. Thanks.
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, "message/register.html", {'form': form})
```

**register.html**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a form `RegisterForm` and add the process of cleaning of mobile to `clean_mobile` function in `forms.py`. Then in your `views.py`, you can access all the form data using `form.cleaned_data` dictionary.

You can do something like below:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = forms.CharField()
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        rep = ['+', '-', ' ', '.']
        for i in rep:
            mobile = mobile.replace(i, '')
        return mobile
```

**views.py**

```
@transaction.atomic
def Register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['mobile'], form.cleaned_data['email'], '1234', first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
            u.save()

            p = UserProfile.objects.create(user=u, company=form.cleaned_data['company'], mobile=form.cleaned_data['mobile'])
            p.save()

            return HttpResponse("Registration complete! Please head over to the <a href='/login/'>login page</a> to start using your SMS panel.")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, "message/register.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll choose this as the answer as soon as I make it work. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. It works perfectly. I was wondering if I wanted to provide a small note after a certain field, i.e. after the mobile field I want to say _Please include country code_ how can I do that?

Comment: You can add the required html between `mobile` field using `{{form.mobile}}`. Something like: `<div class="mobile " id="reg_mobile">
    <p>Please include country code</p>
    {{form.mobile}}
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

after `if form.is_valid() == True` django creates a cleaned_data method with which you can call for the cleaned form data into your view.

You might want something like this:

```
def Register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        fname = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        lname = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid

also what does your Form object look like in forms.py?